# MongoDB Export date parsing issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

I'm having trouble executing a date range search using MongoExport.exe. It keeps trying to parse "05-2017" as "2006".

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongoexport.exe /h servername /p 27017 /d database /c collection /q "{'received_time': { '$gte' : {'$date':'19-05-2017'}, '$lte' : {'$date':'20-05-2017'}}}"
2017-05-22T20:36:31.685+0100    error validating settings: parsing time "19-05-2017" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "5-2017" as "2006"
2017-05-22T20:36:31.686+0100    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

However, if I run the following in MongoDB Compass, it executes as expected:

```
{received_time: { $gte : {$date:"2017-05-19"}, $lte : {$date:"2017-05-20"}}}
```

Any help in regards to resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/Date/

Comment: The documentation talks about setting a date variable. I'm trying to run this query from within the command line. I can't set a variable.

Comment: I'm saying try using the dates mongo likes. Your example is using day month year but I think mongo prefers year month day.

Comment: In the example here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/ it uses the year month day format.

Comment: @MikeCheel You should post that as an answer; MongoDB does indeed require the use of ISODate format.